# Exporting Figma smart animation into a GIF?

Tags: figma

In figma, I have 5 "frames". Each one has a spot where I can click and see the next screen. I used smart animation to move some of the elements around.

What I would like to do is export this animation into a gif so I can use it on a webpage as a demo. Is that possible, and if it is - how?

File> exporting - but there are no options to select from, so it just exports 5 png files.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can export a GIF from Figma. To do this, simply select the frame you want to export as a GIF in the timeline and click on the **Export** button in the top bar.

In the Export window that pops up, select **GIF** as the file format and choose your desired settings.

Comment: Thanks. I don't have an option to select format in the window popup. What am I missing?

Comment: https://www.figma.com/community/plugin/878338850782783595/GIF-Export maybe try this

Answer (score -1):

Also you can use Figma plugin i.e Export Gif.